# Publish performance for Habitat VS 2017 and VS 2015

Tags: habitat

We are two developers working together on a Sitecore project, based on Habitat. I'm using VS 2017, while my colleague is using VS 2015. Our computers are roughly the same, with mine having more memory and more hard disk. Other than that, hardware specs are pretty much identical.

When I run the "publish all projects" task in taskrunner, it takes north of 8 minutes to complete (~50 projects now). When he runs the same, it takes him about 2.5 minutes to complete. The difference is huge and consistent.

What am I missing here? I don't want to downgrade to VS 2015. Is there something that I could do to reduce the time it takes to build/publish?

Regards,
Yiannis

Comment: Sounds like SSD versus spinny drives. How "roughly the same" are those PCs?

Comment: Since Habitat is a demo website, you'll likely find some benefits to starting with a clean project and only adding in features you need.

Comment: @MarkCassidy both have the same CPU (intel Core i7), mine has 16Gb RAM, my colleague's has 8. We both have SSD, mine came pre-installed, his was installed as an upgrade. Actually, if you can have a side-by-side installation of both 2015 and 2017, you'll see that the SAME solution, on the SAME computer, will publish in about 1/4 of the time on vs2015. So I doubt that this is a matter of hardware configuration.

Comment: @MichaelWest that's what we did, actually. We pretty much start with the entire Foundation layer from Habitat (except Theming, which we've replaced with our own version), and we develop Feature and Project on our own from scratch.

Comment: What versions of SQL are you using? Are you both on the same? Do you have the same SQL Editions (Standard, Web, Enterprise, Express) as well?

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel yes, the setup is the same, we both use SQL 2016 (actually, we both installed SQL from the same MSI file). In general, as I said, even on the same machine, with side-by-side installations of VS2015 and 2017, the difference is there, so it's not a hardware issue, and not an issue of any other program setup. It's purely Visual Studio related.